# Access DLookUp using variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I cannot seem to get the following code to run. I appear to be having an issue with using sHostName in my Dlookup statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim sHostName, LNum As String
sHostName = Environ$("computername")
LNum = DLookup("LineNumber", "tblLineNumber", "ComputerName = sHostName")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Access DLookUp using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493863/ms-access-dlookup-using-variables)

Comment: Note that `sHostName` has not been declared as a string, but rather a variant - you need to implicitly state the type = `Dim sHostName As String, LNum As String`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value of the `sHostName` variable.

```
DLookup("LineNumber", "tblLineNumber", "ComputerName = '" & sHostName & "'")
```

Comment: Now I get a Run-time error '94' Invalid use of null

Comment: See this on how to properly handle the `DLookup()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67720613/access-dlookup-runtime-94-error-invalid-use-of-null/67723044#67723044